# org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 30000 millis

Tags: udp, apache-camel, fuseesb, mina

I currently working on two FUSE project which is interconnected.
so i've tried to send Datagram packet from one project to another project using apache Camel Mina udp endpoint with custom codec.
My problem is that datagram packet is received by other project although it will throws the timeout exception in project1.

Please give me the Suggestion why it so happen and how to solve it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing request/reply over that transport. And the was no reply coming back, and so after 30 seconds, there is a timeout exception.

If you do not want to do request/reply but one-way instead, then configure the camel-mina component to sync=false.

And if you want to do request/reply you can raise the timeout to be higher than 30 seconds if you need more time.

See the camel-mina docs: http://camel.apache.org/mina

Comment: As per Your suggestion i've put sync=false in route and its working fine.
but in some routes i need reply back from recipient, so in that i've set 1min of timeout but still getting the same issue.

Thanks Once Again.

Comment: If you only sometimes sends back a reply. Then you need still to send back a "NO REPLY" so the caller knows there is not going to be any "real reply" message. So on the "server" side figure out this, and send back a "NO REPLY" or the "real reply". Then you can have sync=true configured.